# A question about Rings (invertible)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be a ring. Suppose that there exist an element **r ∈ R** with **r^n  =0**, for some **n  ≥ 1**.  Prove that **1-r** is invertible.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$
(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{m-1})=1-r^m.
$
(Why?)